# StackPanel , Border won't draw properly in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

```
<StackPanel  BorderBrush="LightGray" Width="200" Height="32" BorderThickness="1">
    <TextBlock Text="hai" FontSize="14" Height="20" LineHeight="20"   Margin="12 6 0 6"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The bottom border of StackPanel won't render properly, when I set TextBlock margin as (12 6 0 6).
If I set the margin as (12 6 0 0),it works fine. I don't know what's really happening here. Can any one explain it?

Comment: I guess it doesn't fit the size of the panel. Try to change `Height` to `MinHeight`.

Comment: I can't change height,its fixed. I Need explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the total of `TextBlock.Height` and `margin.Top` and `margin.Bottom` exceeds the height of internal space of Stackpanel.

In your scenario, you have set `StackPanel.BorderThickness` to 1, which causes that the internal height of Stackpanel is 30. If you set margin as (12 6 0 6), the total of TextBlock.Height and margin.Top and margin.Bottom is 32, it exceed 30, so the textblock cover the border bottem of stackpanel.

For example, if you set the StackPanel. BorderThickness to 4, as follows:

```
<StackPanel  BorderBrush="LightGray" Width="200" Height="32" BorderThickness="4">
    <TextBlock Text="hai" FontSize="14" Height="20" LineHeight="20"   Margin="12,2,0,2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

As you can see, the internal height is 24 and the textblock height is 20, so we need to set the total of margin.Top and margin.Bottom to be less than 4, such as (12 2 0 2),(12 2 0 1),(12 2 0 0)